# can anyone find out the error in this knockout js code

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, requirejs

this is phtml file located in Namespace_ModuleName/view/adminhtml/templates/js_time.phtml

```
<div>
    <h4>Current Time is:</h4><span id="time_show" data-bind="text: currentTime()"></span>
</div>


<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "body" : {
             "timejs": "Pixelnet_Blog/js/timejs"
        }
    }
</script>
```

And used js file is Namespace_ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/js/timejs.js

```
define(['ko'], function(ko) {
    return function(config) {
        var currentTimeViewModel = function() {
            var self = this;
            self.currentTime = ko.observable();
            setInterval(function() {
                var currentTime = new Date();
                self.currentTime(currentTime.toLocaleTimeString());
            }, 1000);
        };
        ko.applyBindings(new currentTimeViewModel(), document.getElementById('time_show'));
    }
});
```

When page is rendered it should show current time. But it does not do that. In console it shows error *Unable to process binding "text: function(){return currentTime() }*
I cannot find why it is showing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below files:

**PHTML File**:

```
<div id="time_show" data-bind="scope:'time_show'">
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "time_show": {
                    "component": "VendorName_ModuleName/js/timejs"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</div>
```

**JS File**:

```
define(
['jquery', 'uiComponent', 'ko']
,function ($, Component, ko) {
    'use strict';
        return Component.extend({

        defaults: {
            template: 'VendorName_ModuleName/test'
        },

        currentTime: function () {
            var currentTime = new Date();
            return currentTime.toLocaleTimeString();
        }
        });
}
);
```

**HTML File**:

```
<div>
    <h4>Current Time is:</h4><span id="time_show" data-bind="text: currentTime()"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @NathaOdedara . worked!!

Comment: @mrshiam Great to see it worked, Please do upvote if it helped you. Thanks!